# Using XSLT, how do I match an attribute with regex using a variable in a .NET project?

Tags: .net, xml, regex, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am working on a .NET project which converts an xml file into a different format using XSLT.

I have original xml like this (this is just the relevant section):

```
<video>
    <part ids="pt1">
        <title>Title1</title>
    </part>
    <part ids="pt2 pt3">
        <title>Title2</title>
    </part>
    <part ids="pt4">
        <title>Title3</title>
    </part>
</video>
```

In my xslt file I have a variable `$partid` which is set fine as something like `pt2`. I then wanted to use this to find the `<title>` within the `<part>` which contained the variable `$partid` in the attribute `ids`.

I was doing this originally with the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/video/part[contains(@ids, $partid)]/title"/>
```

However, I have now realised this runs into problems if the `$partid` is something like `pt1` but there exists a `<part>` element with `ids` as `pt12` as well as a `<part>` element with `ids` as `pt1`. As this will match both.

I thought I could just swap it to use `matches()` instead of `contains()` and use a regex like this:

```
matches(@ids, '(^'+$partId+' | '+$partId+' | '+$partId+'$ |^'+$partId+'$)')
```

However, it seems I'm restricted to XSLT 1.0 which does not allow `matches()`. Any ideas on how I could proceed with this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no regex support in XSLT 1.0. To eliminate the ambiguity between `pt1` and pt `12`, you can do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/video/part[contains(concat(' ', @ids, ' '), concat(' ', $partid, ' '))]/title"/>
```

A better solution would be upstream of you: there's really little point in using XML that way.

Comment: Awesome solution. The simplicity of it is brilliant. Wish I had thought of it. Many thanks.